# Borrar documentos en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una base de datos en mongo con una colección que tiene unos 6.000.000 de documentos.

Me gustaría saber cómo borrar todos los documentos sin borrar ni la base de datos ni la colección.

Vi que con `remove` se puede hacer, pero me cabe la duda de si con ese comando también se borra la colección, pues no quiero que eso pase.

Uso robo 3t.

Comment: Es lo más sano borrar la colección mongodb cuando intentas hacer un insert y la colección no existe la creará por eso son base de datos nosql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usé [`deleteMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/):

```
db.coleccion.deleteMany({})
```

y borró todos los documentos sin borrar la colección.